# Overflow hidden causes child elements to appear on own line

Tags: html, css

The `overflow: hidden` in `.container` causes the `p` tag to sort of drop down onto it's own line instead of wrapping around. Why is this?

```css
.container {
 background-color: green;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.floated {
 float: left;
 background-color: cyan;
}
p {
 background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='floated'>
   Floated Div
  </div>
  <p>Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `clear: both;` for the p tag

Comment: add `margin: 0;` to `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra spacing you're seeing comes from the paragraph margins and the way they're treated.

When adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container you're  creating a block formatting context. The margins of the paragraph element will be contained within `.container`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

To align the paragraph with your floated element, remove the paragraph element's top margin:

```
p {
    background-color: pink;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```